# INDEX and Partial MATCH in Sheets

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, match, wildcard, google-sheets-formula

```
=INDEX(Sheet17!$B$2:$B$50,MATCH(C5,Sheet17!$A$2:$A$50,0))
```

Short version:
This formula works when C5 is an exact match for text in Sheet 17 Column A, but I want to be able to match part of c5 (a keyword or phrase in C5) to that keyword or phrase in Sheet 17 Column A.

Details: 
For my home budget and expense tracking, I'm using INDEX and MATCH to
return a piece of text (a label I use for the expenditure) from Sheet17 Column B
based on matching C5 (the description in my check register)
to a keyword or phrase in Column A Sheet17!$A$2:$A$50 
AND IT WORKS when the text in C5 (in this case) is an exact match for the text in the column to look up against Sheet17!$A$2:$A$50

But I want to be able to match PART of C5 to Sheet 17 Column A and return the result

I've tried using wildcards around C5 but that doesn't help.

This works for exact matches between C5 and a keyword or phrase in Sheet 17 Col. A

```
=INDEX(Sheet17!$B$2:$B$50,MATCH(C5,Sheet17!$A$2:$A$50,0))
```

When I put wildcards around C5 such as "*"&C5&"*"
I get the error message "Did not find value (the full text of C5) in the MATCH evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(Sheet17!$B$2:$B$50, MATCH(FILTER(Sheet17!$A$2:$A$50, 
 SEARCH("*"&C5&"*", Sheet17!$A$2:$A$50)), Sheet17!$A$2:$A$50, 0))
```

[image: 0]

### _______________________________________________________________

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(C3:C, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Sheet17!A2:A)), Sheet17!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LPAIscExuUA30pqd4XO0vMHqrNw0wVUsw5GRT6HyYbI/edit#gid=1245759701)

Comment: Still getting errors: [Main Sheet](https://imgur.com/Lpt47Bq)  &   [Sheet 17](https://imgur.com/cKRf48F)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m_Vwch3p0_Vk36i6l4OaZhT6n3XAwUOvZPaDhrQ6vaA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Oops. Fixed. Thanks for your patience.